# HTML/CSS - give li class

Tags: html, css

Just trying to get the (.portfoliocategs) category menu on this site to have a different colour highlight for each li.

[link to website in below comment]

As you can see at the moment they're all blue. I would like to be able to specify either a class or colour for each category li listed.

Any ideas on how this could be done?

EDIT: This is the code for the category menu - I'm not sure how to add a CSS class to each seperate category as it seems to grab "all categories" from the php??

```
<?php  if(is_category() && in_category($current_id) || post_is_in_descendant_category($current_id)){?>
    <h1 style="display:none"> <?php single_cat_title(); ?> </h1>

    <ul class="portfolioCategs">
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link(get_option('boldy_portfolio'))?>">All projects</a></li>
```

$categories = get_categories('hide_empty=1&child_of='.$categs);
                    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
                    echo "".$catname."\n";
                    echo ('cat_ID).'">'.$cat->cat_name.'');
                    }
                ?>

Comment: It wouldn't let me post an image also - so here is an example of the colour hover menu.. http://www.some-things.net/images/somethings_hover.png

Comment: Sorry for the horrible formatting - the code box didn't work well with this excerpt.

Comment: This is the link to the website in question
http://www.some-things.net/?cat=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking just CSS right?

Something like this?

```
ul.portfolioCategs li a.cat3:hover {background-color: #660099; }
ul.portfolioCategs li a.cat13:hover {background-color: #CC3300; }
ul.portfolioCategs li a.cat14:hover {background-color: #FF6600; }
ul.portfolioCategs li a.cat17:hover {background-color: #FF6666; }
ul.portfolioCategs li a.cat19:hover {background-color: #FF6699; }
ul.portfolioCategs li a.cat20:hover {background-color: #FF66CC; }
ul.portfolioCategs li a.cat21:hover {background-color: #FF66FF; }
```

Just remove the :hover if you want a constant background.

Make sure the link tag has the corresponding category.

```
<a class="cat13" href="http://www.some-things.net/?cat=13">Fashion</a>
```

PS. dont' tag this as PHP and Wordpress when it's only CSS and HTML :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - please see my below answer with the code.